# Missing \begin{document}, \count22 and a mathchar give infinite font-loading attempts

Tags: latex-base

After some expected errors (missing `\begin{document}`, missing number treated as zero, missing `$` inserted) the following code produces an infinite loop where LaTeX attempts to load the font `^^@^^@OT1+cmr`, the font `^^@^^@^^@OT1+cmr`, the font `^^@^^@^^@^^@OT1+cmr` and so on until running out of grouping levels.

```
a
\count22
\par
\alpha
```

Changing `\count22` to `\count21` or `\count23` makes the loop disappear.  I'm quite puzzled.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `latex.ltx` we find

```
\countdef\m@ne=22 \m@ne=-1
```

and your code sets `\count22` to zero, due to error recovery.

Changing the value of minus one to zero is not the best thing to do, I'm sure you agree with that.

In particular, the code for font loading sets `\endlinechar\m@ne` and this is the reason for all those ASCII NUL you see.

Comment: Oops, of course!  My question actually stemmed from trying to understand why `\int_const:Nn \c_foo_int { foo }` gives such a horrible loop, and `\count22` came from `\c_minus_one` which is set equal to `\m@ne`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Probably `\c_minus_one` should be directly set to `-1` without relying on legacy code.

Comment: @egreg Not really possible: you can't `\chardef` a negative value so you have to use a `\count`

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, but you're not required to use `\count22`